# How can I restrict my search for a tag that has been made a synonym

Tags: support, tag-synonym-process

Android is a big and popular topic, so there are now a large number of tags that deal with specific smaller parts of the subject.

A number of these are currently (probably incorrectly) marked as synonyms of the android tag - specifically

- android-tablet (lots of reasons that a question relates to only tablets, not phones or Android in general)
- android-manifest (a key controlling file for an Android app, hence needing specific questions)

I don't have the reputation to vote to split these synonyms apart again, but I would like to search to find just the questions that use the original tag, without ending up with the thousands of answers from the tag they are currently marked as a synonym of.

How do I do this:

- typing [android-manifest] in the search box gets autochanged to [android]
- going to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android-manifest redirects me to the same android results as my first approach
- searching for "[android-manifest] -[android]" does correctly show me items with the tag I want, but unfortunately since most of them (legitimately) include the wider tag, it's not at all useful

Comment: IMO, only SEDE.

Comment: You could ask for de-synomize a tag but in case that doesn't get enough votes you can use [this sede query](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/218447?tagname=android-manifest) as an alternative. Do remember that SEDE is only updated once a week.

Comment: And here is the query that gives away the user that suggested that synonym: http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/218448/who-synomized-a-tag?tagname=android-manifest

Comment: That last info can also be found [here](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/synonyms?filter=active&tab=master)

Comment: Is there anything I should be doing to remove the "possible duplicate" flag from this question?  It is clearly not a duplicate of the indicated question - though having been flagged as such appears to have persuaded a number of readers to already vote for closure.  The correct answer, of you have to use SEDE to do this, actually appears in these comments, and will be useful to future people facing similar problems of finding the original posts that have since been (correctly or incorrectly) mapped onto a synonym.

Comment: No, you can't but ping me as soon as it gets closed, I'll vote to reopen...

Comment: @zmarties, The question is still a duplicate, even if the answers are not. Personally, I think those two questions would benefit from being merged, as the answer given here would benefit the original question just as much as it does this current one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your question, I don't think it's possible to search for questions with a tag that has been set as a synonym for another tag. You shouldn't need to do this if the tags are genuinely synonymous.

I agree that these were bad tag synonyms, so I removed them. Unfortunately, [android-tablet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android-tablet) looks like it might have already been merged, so no questions exist with that tag.

Comment: Thanks - that wasn't my initial objective in asking the question, but I can't argue with the outcome.  The comments on the question actually did show clearly how to do the search I wanted - but indirectly using SEDE rather than on the live data at Stack Overflow itself.

Comment: Does this removal of tag synonyms take a while to have an effect?  I can now search for the [android-manifest] tag, and the auto correction to [android] no longer occurs, but I still get the same list of results as if I had searched for [android].  Additionally I can't edit the tag for the [android-tablet] tag, since http://stackoverflow.com/tags/android-tablet/info states page not found.

Comment: @zmarties It looks like there are some caching issues going on right now. This should clear up soon.

Comment: @zmarties The [android-manifest](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android-manifest) tag is working now. You won't be able to edit the tag wiki for [android-tablet] until at least one question has that tag.