# Answers tagged with synonyms are not included in /topusers result

Tags: bug

I was trying to find out the top users on the [uwp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/uwp) tag and noticed that the link redirected me to https://stackoverflow.com/tags/win-universal-app/topusers so the [uwp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/uwp) tag must be remapped to [win-universal-app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/win-universal-app).

But then I found that not all my answers on [uwp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/uwp) get mapped over. My [profile](https://stackoverflow.com/users/231837/justin-xl?tab=tags) says I have answered 43 questions on [uwp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/uwp) and 26 on [win-universal-app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/win-universal-app); however, if you have a look at the */topusers* link above, it's showing only 25.

If I specifically ask for my answers on [uwp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/uwp) by this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=votes&q=user%3a231837%20%5buwp%5d%20is%3aanswer), some of my top voted questions (e.g. [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32108362/adding-a-swipe-gesture-to-open-splitview-pane/32110867#32110867) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32088500/adaptivetrigger-and-datatemplate/32092547#32092547)) aren't even listed there.

Is this a bug or am I missing something obvious?

Comment: I recently learned that [this is a fun, confusing, apparently-by-design behavior of tag synonyms](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/316841/should-my-reputation-for-a-tag-include-reputation-for-synonyms-of-that-tag) (see comments). You will need a moderator to merge the tags to get reasonable behavior.

Comment: Thanks @CodyGray. So I am not the only one confused. :) How do we ask a moderator to take a look at this?

Comment: They lumber by this here outpost occasionally. You have asked in the right place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hover over the number *in front* of the tag. You'll see you have 1 *question* asked on [win-universal-app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/win-universal-app) and only 25 *answers.*

[image]

As for the search on the tag, that's not so much a bug as a [rather difficult to work around feature.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/268990/2607247) Since [uwp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/uwp) is a synonym of [win-universal-app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/win-universal-app) in the system, when you search on [uwp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/uwp) you get results *instead* for [win-universal-app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/win-universal-app).

When tags are made synonyms of other tags, they're linked to the main tag and you get automatically redirected to the main tag. If you try to post a new question with the synonym, the tag will be replaced with the main tag or removed if the main tag has already been added.

However, old questions tagged with the synonym don't get automatically retagged at that point. This only happens on a tag *merge.* Once that happens with these tags, as I'm sure it will, your answers posted to the synonym will show up under the main tag instead and you will have (barring answers posted between now and a merge) 68 [win-universal-app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/win-universal-app) answers.

Comment: Actually, I would have thought the system would somehow combine that 43 questions with (26 - 1) and the result would surely be greater than 25.

Comment: Apologies, had a meeting pop up _just_ after I hit the post button. Currently, they _are_ two separate tags. So while it's a pain, it does make a bit of sense. Once they're merged or whatever ends up happening (a merge of the tags sounds 100% appropriate to me) then those values will be combined and you'll have 67 answers (not counting any more you post before then) on the win-universal-app tag.

Comment: OK that's how it works... Thanks. But would they always be merged at some time?

Comment: If I remember correctly, a moderator has to merge them and it's never an automatic process. We like to have eyes on things, to make sure that the synonym link is accurate before we merge the tags.